# How to quickly change white balance on Nikon D5600 in aperture priority mode?

Tags: nikon, white-balance, nikon-d5600

On my old camera, Nikon D50, you would press <kbd>WB</kbd> and rotate the wheel. I now bought Nikon D5600 and am testing it out. I need to take picture of something where the auto WB does not cut it.

Is there an easy way to quickly toggle it between modes, like I could on D50?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but in the manual I read that you can do white balance bracketing. Without knowing much more about your situation, I can't say if it's helpful or not, but perhaps worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to change the WB normally is using the i button on the back. Otherwise it needs to be changed in the menu.

More info can be found here:
https://imaging.nikon.com/support/digitutor/d5600/functions/whitebalance.html

Alternatively you could use the Fn button to change the WB. This can be set in setting F1 of the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Not precisely what you asked, but one of the main reasons to shoot RAW is that you can change white balance in post at will.  From RAW you can make any equivalent change that a preset used shooting JPEG would.

What this does mean is that you move the issue of selecting white balance to post processing.  At that point you have the widest possible latitude for WB choice.

This also frees you from worrying about white balance when shooting.  You can still use Auto WB to get a JPEG (RAW+JPEG) and use the RAW to work from when AutoWB lets you down.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. There are situations where the luxury of shooting raw files and doing color correction later is not possible. Sometimes, for a variety of reasons, it needs to be done as closely as possible *in camera*.

Comment: @MichaelC *Not precisely what you asked ...* starts my post for that exact reason. :-)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all. It would only be useful in case I was unaware that RAW format exists, which seems unlikely for a person buying a second camera. The only thing this answer does is that it removes my question from Unanswered question filter, making it less likely that I will ever get an answer.

Comment: And fun fact: the possibility that someone will suggest RAW went through my mind when posting the question, but I concluded that the question is precise enough that it won't happen.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica Your idea that someone buying a second camera would not know about RAW is absolutely not the experience I've had with questions here and on other photography related website.  Even if they've heard the term, they quite often have no idea what it is or what uses it can be put to.  DSLRs and MILCs are consumer items these days and most users expect to turn it on (like a phone) and learn next to nothing.  Would it were otherwise.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica Please also note that answers (and questions) on SE are not exclusively for the benefit of the person posting the question.  So answers often address a broader audience than the OP.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica out of curiosity, why is shooting RAW not possible in your situation?

Comment: I always shoot RAW, still I like to set my WB so that the preview on the LCD looks good, and because it gives me a good starting point when I process in Nikon software. Most of the time WB is fine as is and in some cases I fine tune it a bit, it saves a lot of time in post.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the configurable Fn button ( it is near the top left of the camera ). You can set it to WB . I think the default is ISO.

You can set it under Menu -> custom settings -> f1. Assign fn button. Once you have set that , you can use  it to change WB while taking pictures without having to go into any other menus or settings.